# Tengo un problema con la instanciacion de arrays de objetos

Tags: java, array, poo

Tengo un problema con el código de mi trabajo, intento crear un objeto dentro que pertenece a un array de objetos y me da el error **NullPointerException**. Os indico el código a continuación:

```
public class Concesionario {
    
    //private String marca, matricula, descripcion, propietario, dniPropietario;
    //private int km, precio;
    //private LocalDate fechaMatricula;
    
    Vehiculo[] coche = new Vehiculo[50];
    
    public Concesionario(){
        
    }
    public void nuevoCoche(String marca, String matricula, int km, LocalDate fechaMatricula, String descripcion, int precio, String propietario, String dniPropietario){
        int i = 0;
        if (i<coche.length){
            coche[i] = new Vehiculo();
            coche[i].setKilometros(km);
            coche[i].setMatricula(matricula);
            coche[i].setMarca(marca);
            i++;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Demasiados coches");
        }
            
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo mas probable es que al momento de imprimir los valores te este lanzando ese error y pues que pasa? tu array esta declarado para  50 valores y vos ingresas 1 o 3 pero no los 50 , al ser un array de tipo String al crearse todos los 50 valores tienen como dato `default null` al tu ingresar un dato este valor cambia pero el resto de los 50 sigue como `null` es por ello el error entonces...Al momento de imprimir puedes poner una condicional `if` para que imprima solo los valores que son distinto a null

```
int j=0
public void imprimirDatos(){
        
       for (Vehiculo c:coche) {
          if(c!=null){
             System.out.println("Auto #: "+ (j+1)); 
             System.out.println(c.getMarca());
             System.out.println(c.getMatricula());
             //otros datos
             j++;
          }
       }
    }
```

otro detalle en el método `nuevocoche()` estas declarando int =0; y que pasa aunque aumente dentro del método,cada vez que tu uses ese método `i` va ha seguir siendo 0,por que asi esta declarado, por ende en vez de ocupar un nueva posición en el arreglo lo que va a ser es sobrescribir la posición 0 ,para evitar ello es mejor declararlo fuera del método

```
  int i=0;
    public void nuevoCoche(String marca, String matricula, int km, LocalDate fechaMatricula, String descripcion, int precio, String propietario, String dniPropietario){
        
        if (i<coche.length){
            coche[i] = new Vehiculo();
            coche[i].setKilometros(km);
            coche[i].setMatricula(matricula);
            coche[i].setMarca(marca);
            i++;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Demasiados coches");
        }
            
    }
```

Comment: Hola, veo lo que quieres decir, pero lo que busco es iniciar uno solo de los objetos del array, el método lo invoco desde la clase principal y es cuando se da el caso de añadir un nuevo vehiculo del array.

Comment: @DanielBolaMartinez cada vez que llames al método nuevocoche en la clase principal se va generar un solo objeto en el array

Comment: si, eso es lo que quiero, que cada vez que llamo al método se me cree un solo objeto del array, no busco imprimir, solo crearlos.

Comment: @DanielBolaMartinez eso es lo que hace el método nuevocoche crea solo uno pruebalo ;)